# Run java application on Tomcat with Gradle

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project structure as follows:

```
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── MessageServlet.java
    │   └── webapp
    │       ├── META-INF
    │       │   └── context.xml
    │       ├── WEB-INF
    │       │   └── web.xml
    │       ├── index.html
    │       └── style.css
    └── test
    └── java
```

I also have  a tomcat server which I run using the gradle below. The tomcat server starts and displays the index.html page. But, when I try to run the servlet i get following error message:

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class MessageServlet

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'

def tomcatVersion = '8.0.42'
tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}
```

**QUESTION**

I want to run the project on my tomcat server via this gradle. How do I make the gradle execute MessageServlet.java together with tomcat?

Comment: Please post you web.xml and servlet class(if possible) code